# How to remove blurriness in an image that contains table?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image that is blurred and contains some noise. I have tried [Image Denoising](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_Image_Non-local_Means_Denoising_Algorithm_Noise_Reduction.php) from the following example.

[image]

The code to remove the Gaussian noise from a color image using the Non-local Means Denoising algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("data_5/1.png")
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)           # get b,g,r
rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb

# Denoising

dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img,None,10,10,7,21) 
b,g,r = cv2.split(dst)           # get b,g,r
rgb_dst = cv2.merge([r,g,b])     # switch it to rgb


cv2.imshow('denoising black and white', rgb_dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output of the above code:
[image]

The above code removes some noise. But here some numbers are blurred and the table lines are blurred.

Can anyone suggest me a better solution to remove blurriness and Noise from the above image?

Comment: @zindarod The goal is to recognize the text in each row.

Comment: instead of denoising and ending up with another image why not using an OCR?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I tried OCR but it gives different output since text quality in this image is not better.

Comment: @zindarod I have removed noise in my image and wrote the answer. I need to smoothen the text clearer without noise. Can you please suggest me a solution for smoothening my output image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = cv2.imread('image.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    image = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret,binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    binary = cv2.medianBlur(binary, 3)

    (rows,cols) = image.shape[:2]

    H = cv2.Sobel(binary, cv2.CV_8U, 1, 0, ksize = 5)
    V = cv2.Sobel(binary, cv2.CV_8U, 0, 1, ksize = 5)

    _,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(V, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for cnt in contours:
        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if w < cols/3 and h < rows/3:
            cv2.drawContours(V, [cnt], -1, 0, -1)

    _,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(H, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for cnt in contours:
        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if w < cols/3 and h < rows/3:
            cv2.drawContours(H, [cnt], -1, 0, -1)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    V = cv2.morphologyEx(V, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations = 3)
    H = cv2.morphologyEx(H, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations = 3)

    binary[V == 255] = 0
    binary[H == 255] = 0

    binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)

    api = PyTessBaseAPI()
    api.SetImage(Image.fromarray(binary))
    text = api.GetUTF8Text()
    text = text.split()

    boxes = api.GetComponentImages(RIL.TEXTLINE, True)

    for i, (_, box, _, _) in enumerate(boxes):
        (x,y,w,h) = box['x'], box['y'], box['w'], box['h']
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255))
        cv2.putText(image, text[i], (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (255,0,0))

    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: binary]

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

I have tried applying a Gaussian Blur then processing it with adaptive thresholding and result removed noise in the image and blurriness.

```
import cv2 as cv

#input

img = cv.imread('data_5/1.png',0)

#gaussian Blur

img = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (15,15),0)

#adaptive threshold

th3 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\

cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

cv2.imshow('Noise Filtered Image', th3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv.imwrite('data_5/result.png',th3)
```

The output of the above code:

[image]

Can anyone help me to smoothen this image? I want an output quality similar to this table below. Removal of table lines is ok.

My goal is to have an image with clear text.

[image]

Comment: "output quality similar to this table below". Sorry but the quality of the last table is way worse than the initial one.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki The problem is that I need a further better text quality in my output image. Is there any way to improve the text quality in my output image?

Comment: If this does not answer your question, do not post it as an answer edit your question and add the relevant information of your tried attempt. This way the question jumps to the top and more people see it. If it has an answer people may skip it, since it is "answered".